# How to put value 1 when other column is not zero in python?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the table I have

```
|Company | Counts | Date | mean   |
|A       | 100    | 2019 | nan    |
|B       | 200    | 2019 | nan    |
|C       | 300    | 2019 | nan    |
|D       | 400    | 2019 | 1.02   |
|E       | 0      | 2020 | 10.08  |
|F       | 0      | 2020 | 11.11  |
```

I am trying to get this, by replacing `'mean'` with 1 when `'Counts'` is not 0.

```
|Company | Counts | Date | mean    |
|A       | 100    | 2019 | 1       |
|B       | 200    | 2019 | 1       |
|C       | 300    | 2019 | 1       |
|D       | 400    | 2019 | 1       |
|E       | 0      | 2020 | 10.08   |
|F       | 0      | 2020 | 11.11   |
```

Comment: can you please format your dataframe, and what I mean is to remove the dashes so others can paste the dataframe in to their IDE

Comment: Which is the other column that isn't null?

Comment: @orde For future reference: typing `[ask]` produces [ask]. See [SO magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/344593) for more

Comment: I need 1 in mean column when Counts column is not equal to 0

Comment: it's not just `fillna` since we are changing the value for `Company D` as well

Comment: Exactly! @aws_apprentice

Comment: [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: Can you give me an example. Sorry I am new to the coding.!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to change the value of the `mean` column where the condition you stated matches.

```
df.loc[df.Counts != 0, 'mean'] = 1

    Company  Counts  Date      mean
0  A            100  2019         1
1  B            200  2019         1
2  C            300  2019         1
3  D            400  2019         1
4  E              0  2020      10.08  
5  F              0  2020      11.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) and pass in the condition, true value and false values

```
df['mean'] = np.where(df['Counts']>1, 1, df['mean'])
```